# Maven project has JDBC drivers as a dependency, but will not load them without Class.forName

Tags: java, postgresql, maven

I've got a simple servlet set up for testing the connection to my database in which PostgreSQL drivers are loaded as a dependency in Maven. My understanding is that this *should* register the driver on the classpath, but when I try connecting to it, I'm thrown the dreaded `No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/customer_tracker`. However, I'm able to connect no problem if I include the `Class.forName` line.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String URL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/customer_tracker";
    String USER = "hbstudent";
    String PASS = "hbstudent";
    String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    try {

        //works fine when this line is included, error thrown otherwise
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Success!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Releveant snippet from `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.23</version>
    </dependency>
```

The PostgreSQL JDBC jar file is also inside of Tomcat's `lib` folder.

Is there some other trick to getting the driver recognized?

EDIT:
After introducing some debug lines, I'm even more confused. Here's my terminal output:

```
GETTING CONNECTION
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/hb_student_tracker
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at com.eyanu.customertracker.HelloServlet.doGet(HelloServlet.java:20)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
ENTERING TRY BLOCK
GETTING CONNECTION
CONNECTION MADE: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1f758f9e
ENTERING TRY BLOCK
GETTING CONNECTION
CONNECTION MADE: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@35c5b50a
ENTERING TRY BLOCK
GETTING CONNECTION
CONNECTION MADE: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@9ad78a4
```

Why is the code looping so many times after running it?

Comment: No, you should not be packaging the JDBC driver into your WAR. You should be configuring the JDBC driver in your POM as `provided`, to avoid that bundling at build time. JDBC drivers belong in a special folder in Tomcat, not with your app.

Comment: And you should not be calling `Class.forName` to load JDBC drivers. In modern Java, JDBC drivers are automatically loaded via the Java Service Provider (SPI) facility. Instead you should be using the `DataSource` interface to insulate your app’s code from deployment configuration details such as database server address, username, and password. You should configure Tomcat to provide your web app with a `DataSource` object, at runtime, pre-configured for connecting to a db server. This way you need not recompile your Java web app code just because the database address or password changed.

Comment: All the issues in both my comments have been addressed already on Stack Overflow. Some of these existing Questions and Answers were even authored by me. So search to learn more.